# How to name the repository for Travis CI and R

Tags: r, rstudio, travis-ci

I am trying to use Travis with my r package. I am using Rstudio. The Travis account is set up with my github and the relevant repository called `MyPackagR` is switched on

The package in Rstudio is called `MyPackagR`

I try: `devtools::use_travis()` and the browser pops up and tells me:

```
We couldn't find the repository 
sebastiz/MypackageR
```

For some reason the middle letter is being lower-cased so the repository is not found. I don't know where Travis is getting the name from but I also tried

```
devtools::use_travis("/home/rstudio/MyPackageR")
```

with the same result

Is there a way I can explicitly tell Travis the name of the target repository?

Comment: What does `devtools:::github_info(".")` report? That's ultimately where the info is coming from. You rly shld try to match case on GH and local dir.